# Converting stroked path to shape with javascript

Tags: javascript, raphael, d3.js

Is there a way to convert a stroked path to a shape using javascript? Do any libraries offer this as a build in feature?

I know Illustrator has this function, so a possible solution would be to copy the SVG image on the screen and move it to Illustrator, but if you could do that, would you lose all the associated meta-data stored as attributes?

Answer (score 2):

> *[I]s there a way to convert a stroked path to a shape using JavaScript?*

Yes, there's a way to convert an SVG path stroke into an outlined shape. Unfortunately, it is not a prepackaged function built into SVG. The way to do it is called Math. You'd need to account for bézier curves, miter settings, linecaps, linejoins, and dasharrays. As @inhan noted you might use various functions to help you or to approximate it, but none of them are going to do the math for you. It is *possible*, but it is not by any means *easy*…in JavaScript.

> *[W]ould there be a way to copy the svg image on the screen and move it to Illustrator?*

Sure, that's easy.

1. Open your D3.js SVG-based illustration in a web browser.
2. Open the Developer Tools (or Firebug).
3. Find the element you want, right-click and choose "Copy as HTML" or "Copy SVG".
4. Paste the code into a text editor and wrap it with SVG.
5. Open the SVG in Illustrator.
6. Outline the path(s) you want.
7. Save as SVG
8. Copy/paste the SVG code Illustrator exported into…wherever you want.

But what does this gain you? Certainly nothing that works with your D3.js visualization.

> *But if you could do that, would you lose all the associated meta-data stored as attributes?*

What *are* you talking about? If you are talking about attributes in the source code, then you only lose it if you don't copy/paste the attributes onto the result. If you are talking about JavaScript data bound to a visualization running in the web browser, of **course** you are going to lose the data if you round trip through Adobe Illustrator.

Your questions make so little sense to me that I have a feeling that I must be missing what your needs/goals are. What are you *really* trying to accomplish?

Comment: I enjoyed reading your reply! FWIW, when I said attributes, I meant class, id, data, what-have you--so you got that right. I was really just interested in creating an SVG path with multiple strokes, one stroke for color, and a secondary stroke on mouseover. I couldn't find any information in the SVG spec, so I got to thinking about turning stroked paths into shapes so I could then apply a second stroke.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Element.getTotalLength()` and `Element.getSubpath()` functions in Raphaël along with **stoke-width** and **stroke-dasharray** attributes of that path in a function would probably give the result.

Comment: …though you'd need to also take into account the stroke line-cap and line-join options, and implement the proper miter-limit algorithm. What you've basically said is "Yes, there exist some functions that can help with this."

Comment: Yes I skipped those props. I thought Alex could create a function himself and maybe ask again if something is not working as intended with the formula itself. Or was I to write the whole function myself?